# Ruby-on-Rails equivalent to ORM Designer for Symfony?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symfony1

In Symfony i just have to create models with ORM Designer and export it to symfony as a schema.yml and then use a symfony command to create tables, models and forms.

I wonder if there is an equivalent to the RoR so that you dont have to create models manually by hand?

It saves a lot of time using GUI for this kind of tasks and it is less error-prone.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be possible to support RoR in ORM Designer. The trouble is that we know only PHP and wouldn't be able to beta test RoR support and create unit tests. But if there is anybody willing to help, please let us know at support at orm-designer dot com and RoR support can be released within a few months.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the model generator with `script/generate model` to create a model class and [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). A great reference on migrations is [`cheat migrations`](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/migrations/) which is available via the [`cheat`](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/) command.

You could use the scaffold generator as per [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), however scaffolds are "considered harmful" by many (including myself). I prefer to generate an initial migration with `script/generate migration`, tweak it to suit and then create/update my model, routes, controllers and views manually.

If you are still starting out, you will probably find it helpful to run through [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) at least once.

Comment: thanks for reply. but i am wondering if there is a GUI tool for creating models than maybe like ORM Designer export everything to a file/files for rails to generate to actual models/tables? http://www.orm-designer.com/

Comment: I am not aware of any GUI tools to do this.